# Removing Special and Invalid characters in a String

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have been working on creating a Product Feed for a third party company. The data I am working with has all sorts on invalid, special characters, double spacing, etc. They have also requested that the data is HTML encoded, where special characters are used.

An example of some data that would be passed = "Buy Kitchen

Aid Artisan™ Stand Mixer 4.8L "

```
        try
        {
            var removeDoubleSpace = Regex.Replace(stringInput, @"\s+", " ");
            var encodedString = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(removeDoubleSpace).Trim();
            var encodedAndLineBreaksRemoved = encodedString.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
            var finalStringOutput = Regex.Replace(encodedAndLineBreaksRemoved, @"(™)|(’)|(”)|(–)", "");

            return finalStringOutput;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return stringInput;
        }
```

I was trying to come up with one method that could be called, to do all the above, in a cleaner way rather than several `Regex` expressions. Or, perhaps, is there just one regex that covers everything?

Comment: You could always write a function that enumerates all the characters in the presented string, and check each character for validity (or pairs of validity, i.e. your space issue.) You could write it so it enumerates them all only once, instead of doing multiple regexes and replacements.

Comment: My 2 cents: *Don't bother.* If you succeed, you will probably end up with a long, complicated, hard to read and basically a *terrible* regular expression. It's better to do 2, 3, even 10 replace actions and keep a readable code, unless you are facing terrible performance issues.

Comment: My example is now more complete and strips everything that is NOT an ASCII character using a white list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a white list not a blacklist, because you can more easily know which letters are acceptable than which letters might be there that are unacceptable. A white list is just that. It's a list of acceptable characters. Create your white list, and remove everything that is not on that list. In your case, a potential white list could include all ASCII characters.

[The following is a white list that captures](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O5E4IZ) all alphanumeric and punctuation characters.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{       
    private static string input = @"Buy Kitchen

Aid Artisan™ Stand Mixer 4.8L ";

    public static void Main()
    {
        var match = Regex
            .Match(input, @"[a-zA-Z0-9\p{P}]+");

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while(match.Success)
        {
            // add a space between matches
            builder.Append(match + " ");
            match = match.NextMatch();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
    }
}
```

Output

```
Buy Kitchen Aid Artisan Stand Mixer 4.8L
```

Comment: The only problem I feel with this approach, is my whitelist would be huge and also mantained. Depending on some of the characters that could be used in future. Thanks though

Comment: The white list need not be huge. In fact, it will be more manageable than your black list will be. You never know when new black list items will arise, and these can take you by more surprise than white list ones can.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit enhanced code:

```
var removeDoubleSpace = Regex.Replace(stringInput, @"\s+", " ");
var encodedString = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(removeDoubleSpace).Trim().Replace("™", string.Empty).Replace("’", string.Empty).Replace("”", string.Empty).Replace("–", string.Empty);
```

You do not need to use `var encodedAndLineBreaksRemoved = encodedString.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");` since newline symbols have been already removed with [`\s+`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) regex (`\s` *matches any white space character including space, tab, form-feed, and so on. Equivalent to [ \f\n\r\t\v].*).

Also, there is no need using a 2nd regex *unless* you plan to remove a certain range of characters, or a class (e.g. all characters inside `\p{S}` shorthand class), thus, I just chained several `string.Replace` methods, right to the trimmed and encoded string.

Output:

```
Buy Kitchen Aid Artisan Stand Mixer 4.8L
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex, linq will do as well:

```
var str = "Buy Kitchen Aid Artisan™ Stand Mixer 4.8L";
var newStr = new string(str.Where(c => !Char.IsSymbol(c)).ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(newStr); // Buy Kitchen Aid Artisan Stand Mixer 4.8L
```